# Google Cloud print on windows 8 is not recognizing XPS driver

Tags: windows-8, google-cloud-print

https://tools.google.com/dlpage/cloudprintdriver

Trying to register a google cloud printer with windows so I can print from word or other programs.  When I try to install this, I get the error "XPS driver is not installed".

Devices and Printers says the contrary.  I can see Microsoft XPS Document Writer.  Is this not the same thing?  The site offers a link to microsoft XPS pack, but it's for XP-7.  Read up on some XPS stuff, says windows 8 changed things to an OXPS format.

anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=267207). You can star the issue to show that it affects you (you will receive email updates).